# How escape sequence is detected in printf?

Tags: c, escaping

I was experimenting with basic c programs and wrote a program like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("hello 0x0a");//0x0a is hex value for \n
   return 0;
}
```

it prints "hello 0x0a".

Is there a way to give escape sequences as decimal or hex value in printf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way - but fhis is actually no feature of printf but part of the language.

C string literals can contain [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) that will be evaluated by the compiler (not by printf at runtime).

The correct escape sequence for a newline written in hex would be `\x0a` (or `\x0A` at your discretion):

```
printf("hello \x0a");
```

Comment: so 0x0a becomes \x0a? Why \0x0a is not used?

Comment: Because `\0x0a` is not a valid escape sequence. `\0` could be the beginning of an escape sequence for an octal number (`\nnn` in the table referenced in my answer), but the parser would stop interpreting it as an escape sequence when it reads the `x`.

Comment: I tried with \10 in decimal, it won't interpret it?

Comment: No. Check the [table from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences). There are 13 valid escape sequences of which one is for hexadecimal and one is for octal constants. There is no escape sequence for decimal values.

Comment: ok so there are escape sequences in decimal, but we can't use their decimal values due to compiler limitation. Is that correct way to understand it? The wiki page did not said anything about octal values of escape sequences too.

Comment: No. There are _no escape sequences for decimal values_.
If you want to interpret a value given in a decomal notation as a character, you can still use `printf` to format that character:
`printf("hello%c", 10);` will also write hello and a newline

Comment: Understood, anything we try to give in decimal value, it will be taken as octal value.

Comment: No. Only a backslash followed by exactly three digits in the range 0...7 will be treated as an octal escape sequence. Would you like to continue this as a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110809/discussion-between-mrigendra-and-florian).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, printing the newline character using its numerical value **0x0a** in ASCII.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int main() 
  {
     printf("Hello,%cworld!", 0x0a);
  }
```

Also Backspace value **0x08**, Horizontal Tab **0x09**. Reference link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).